# How to parse JSON data with Swift Class?

Tags: swift

I want to parse this JSON with swift class using codable, this can be done with struct easily, but how to do the same with class?

```
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"name": "Cake",
"ppu": 0.55,
"batters":
    {
        "batter":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ]
    },
"topping":
    [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
        { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What difference does it make whether its a struct or a class (for decoding purposes)?

Comment: Please share the code you have with struct's

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Yes, [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/), as others have mentioned. Also, did you mean to have two levels for your cupcake batters (`.batters,batter`)? It seems like you'd want only a single level (`.batters`) enclosing the list, as you already have with `.topping` (which you might want to make plural to indicate that it is a list).

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://quicktype.io/ to generate Swift files from a JSON. It will do most of the work for you. You may need to do some cleanup, but overall it does a great job generating the object.